# Edge Animate CC dynamic / animated slider

Tags: slider, jquery-animate, adobe-edge

I want to make a dynamic animated slider with symbols that contain clickable actions vs a slider image only approach. I would like to use a "next" button and a "back" button that will scroll multiple background images that contain clickable links. I can produce a basic image slider with the back and next buttons, but this approach is limited. Any help on how I can do this in Edge Animate CC will be very appreciated.

Comment: Please show code demonstrating what you've tried and explain what seems not to be working with it.

Comment: This is similar to what I would like to make, but in Adobe Edge Animate CC  http://wowslider.com/html5-slider-sunny-fade-demo.html I can make the basic scroll but not animated and dynamic, other than next and back

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for a very simple slideshow a while ago. Came up with this here:

http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/

If you want your Slides to contain any clickable items you will be able to simply add them to the sides div. Just set the picture as a background image in CSS and you are free to develop any clickable items infront.

Here is another tutorial that worked fine for me: http://line25.com/tutorials/build-a-simple-image-slideshow-with-jquery-cycle

To me this is easy to understand and if you are used to jQuery at least a little bit this here will work out fine for you.

Comment: Thanks for the very helpful links, but I'm trying to use Edge Animate CC to do the heavy lifting.